# Simple fields for - Avoid creating if all fields are empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, simple-form

I have a form for a User that has a part that looks like this:

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :uncles, User.new do |uncle| %>
    <%= uncle.input :first_name, :label => "First Name" %>
    <%= uncle.input :last_name, :label => "Last Name" %>
    <%= uncle.input :email%>
<% end %>
```

My question is: How would I go to avoid create this "uncle" user record if all the fields in the simple_fields are empty?

In my User model I have this:

```
has_many     :uncles,
             :through               => :uncles_relationships,
             :source                => :uncle
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you’re using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to create the related model, add a [`reject_if`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) to check for blank fields.

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :uncles, :reject_if => :reject_uncles?

def reject_uncles?(attributes)
  attributes[:first_name].blank? &&
  attributes[:last_name].blank? &&
  attributes[:email].blank?
end
```

Comment: I don't want to reject though. I want the parent form to be submitted, but to avoid creating the "uncle" User record.

Comment: `reject_if` is applying to the nested uncle attributes. The `User` will still be created, just no blank `Uncle`s.

Answer (score 0):

I would try a custom validator perhaps, something like:

```
(User model class)
validate :all_fields_required

private
def all_fields_required
  if first_name && last_name && email then
  # or perhaps: if (first_name != '') && (last_name != '') && (email != '') then
    true
  else
    false
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you should need to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, as @Buck Doyle said. When you used that method, you can build a form for parent and child( as your words), when you submitted form, if the information of child are blank, only information of parent will saved. So how to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for`?

In your User model, you can add this:

```
attr_accessible :uncles_attributes
accepts_nested_attributes_for :uncles, :reject_if => lambda { |attrs| attrs.all? { |key, value| value.blank? } }
```

That is all. Now in your `User` controller, you just need using `save` method to create `User` object, and it will check for you, if info of uncles (children) are blank, only info of parent are saved.